# Why are some features missing from Raster menu in QGIS for linux?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am running QGIS 1.8 in Ubuntu/Linux (13.04), with GDAL 1.10 installed.  There seem to be features missing from GDAL tools that are present in Windows version. For example, I can't find Rasterize or Contour options in the menue, and Clipper only has "extent" option - no "mask to layer", which is what I need!

Am I missing something?  How do I get these additional functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem was addressed by the OSGeo Live DVD team. See this maillist [post](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/ticket/1208) 
THe patch by Jerome Larouche should appear in Ubuntu updates quite soon.